# The window of the Emulator is too big than a mobile screen

Tags: android, eclipse

i have make a small example to test my Android environment, when i launch the execution on the AVD, it looks too big(as if it is a tablet screen). How can i fix the size so that it look like a mobile screen?

[image]

Comment: You can specify the exact size of the display when creating the AVD. Sometimes, the emulator is stretched and "looks" to big. Check if the resolution is the same, then it should fit.

Comment: @Malek check my update in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Set the **Size** of the Emulator You can do this,

```
    Window -> Android SDK and AVD Manager 
    -> Select the virtual device you are using 
    -> Click on Edit -> Skin

    SELECT : Resolution and give the Height and Width say 320 X 480
```

You Should also give **Density** in

```
        Window -> Android SDK and AVD Manager 
        -> Select the virtual device you are using 
        -> Click on Edit -> Hardware 

        SELECT : Abstracted LCD Density and Give Values
        i.e. 240X320 = 120, 320X480 = 160 and 480X800 = 240
```

Comment: I don't have the skin option you are talking about, I have a skin option but not a drop down menu, it is a check box option that doesn't have any other options ..

Answer (score 11):

After the Android Studio 2.2 update, there is no `Emulator` Tab in `Edit Configurations` window.

If you want to scale your emulator, you just need to use this keyboard combination:

> To scale up: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>▲</kbd>
>
> To scale down: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>▼</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

1. In Android Studio: click "Run" -> "Edit Configurations.."
2. On the left side select your current app (its probably selected already)
3. click on the "Emulator" tab
4. check "Additional command line options:" and write "-scale 0.75" (for 75% percent of the original size, use 0.5 for 50%, etc.)
5. Apply your changes, click "ok" and run your emulator

Answer (score 1):

Window -> Android SDK and AVD Manager -> Select the virtual device you are using -> Click on Edit -> Change the skin type to the required theme.

HTH.

Comment: Hi, so what is the Skin resolution to put  that match the resolution of a mobile screen?

Answer (score 1):

You can set screen size while launching an `emulator`.  `Window` -> `Android SDK and AVD Manager` -> Select the `virtual device` -> `Start` -> Check the `Scale display to real size` -> Screen size (in) : `5`

Answer (score 0):

Open the Android SDK Manager. Choose your AVD from the list of virtual devices. Click "EDIT"
Try changing the skin to HVGA or something.

Or if you are running the AVD via eclipse you can even try out the below

- Take Run -> Run Configurations
- Move to the target tab and add the following line to 'Additional Emulator Commmand Line    Options'

  ```
            -scale 0.7
  ```

I hope this works for you