# Emulator contents too large

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, samsung-mobile

Just started with Android Studio. The problem is that my emulator contents (not the emulator window itself) show too big. Following is a snapshot:

[image]

So my question is different than [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359895/android-emulator-screen-too-tall) where the problem seems to be that the emulator window itself is larger than the screen. Also I tried following steps given in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641744/samsung-galaxy-s-ii-avd-android-virtual-device-basic-settings), but that doesn't help much. Anyone can help me with this?

Note: I have already downloaded the skin from vendor's website and supplied correct physical screen size and resolution in the config files.

Comment: Does this happen with every new emulator you create?

Comment: @Ethan: I tried creating the same emulator twice (I have the same physical phone with me, so I was trying to get it running in the emulator too), and it happened on both occasions. The built-in device profiles (such as Nexus 4) however seem to run just normal size.

Comment: Hope this will solve your problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777475/the-window-of-the-emulator-is-too-big-than-a-mobile-screen

Comment: @Ethan: I do not see the options mentioned in that post. They are probably working with Eclipse, not Android Studio.

Comment: @dotNET What is the density shown in the AVD's "Resolution" column?

Comment: @matiash: `320 x 480: mdpi`, which is exactly what the physical dimensions of my phone are. BTW AVD doesn't allow me to set that `mdpi` to any other value. Out of curiosity, I created a duplicate profile and manually edited it to `hdpi`, but even that profile doesn't look any better.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I updated my Android Studio and the emulator looks like it's doing something similar.

Comment: @IntrepidBrit: No. Has been a long time since then. Don't even remember where did I end up with this.

Comment: I just ended up doing a completely fresh install. Not a great solution, but at least I can carry on.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. I was trying to create Nexus 6P device with the following command

```
avdmanager create avd -n nexus6p -k "system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86" -b x86 -c 1000M -d 11
```

Later I read somewhere, there are issues with resolution compatibility of your computer and the device you intend to create. Nexus 6P (in my case, it has id of 11; you can check them with `avdmanager list device` command) is a very high resolution display device. I issued following command

```
avdmanager create avd -n nexus6p -k "system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86" -b x86 -c 1000M -f
```

without specifying any specific device. It asked if I wished to create a custom hardware profile with default answer being no. I simply pressed enter so that it created a standard hardware profile. The resulting avd did not have this problem.
I emulated the device with following command

```
./emulator -avd nexus6p -gpu off -qemu -m 2047 -enable-kvm
```

In my case, switching off gpu was necessary to prevent crashing of the emulated device.